# Find largest prime number below input value

Tags: c, loops

Let me start by saying that I am a beginner. I'm trying to define a function that calculates/identifies the largest prime number below an input value. However, my current approach is flawed.

I've tried implementing a nested for loop. Generating numbers from one below the input down to 1, subsequently running each number through the second loop so as to identify whether or not it is prime. If it is prime (if count == 2) the function is supposed to return the number that was generated by the first loop (n)

I've been permitted to assume that the input will be a positive integer greater than 2.

```
int prime(int maximum)
{
int i, j, count = 0, n;

for (i = 1; i < maximum; i++) {
        n = maximum - i; /* generating number below input value*/ 
        for (j = 1; j <= maximum; j++) {
            if (n % j == 0) { /* testing whether or not it is prime */
                count++;
            } 
        } if(count == 2) {
                break;
            } 
    } 
    return n;
}
```

I'd expect an input of 10 to produce an output of 7, an input of 30 to produce an output of 29 and an input of 100 to produce an output of 97.

However, the function is currently generating an output of 1 - consistently.

The code is not generating any error messages

note: This is my first time utilising this platform, my most sincere apologies if the formatting of my question is incorrect

Comment: Forget about what computer language you are using for the moment. Do you have any confidence in your algorithm/approach? You need to make sure it is logical first then implement the C.

Comment: Take either a debugger or paper and pen and go through your function with some fixed input step by step, writing down or watching the values of all the variables in each step. Watch `count` particularly close. Then you should realize you logic mistake.

Comment: You should be aware that `n % 1 == 0 for ALL n > 0` - you probably *don't want to start the `j` loop at one.

Comment: Newspeak "tasked with defining". Oldspeak "my homework is to".

Comment: Examine the value of  `count`.  It does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are `not resetting the count to 0` in the outer loop. 
This will solve the problem.

Adding further,
There are some other optimizations that can be done in the code too.

You need not run the inner loop `maximum` times, `only n times` will be sufficient as you are checking `whether n is prime or not.`

You can put the `break condition inside the inner for loop` for those whose count has crossed 2 to avoid further iterations.

```
int prime(int maximum)
{
int i, j, count = 0, n;

for (i = 1; i < maximum; i++) {
        count = 0;  # <-----  Reset it to 0.
        n = maximum - i; /* generating number below input value*/ 
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            if (n % j == 0) { /* testing whether or not it is prime */
                count++;
                if(count > 2) # to avoid further iterations as we know, this number is not prime.
                   break;
            } 
        } if(count == 2) {
                break;
            } 
    } 
    return n;
}
```

Comment: You also need to fix the `j` range.